# How to implement two entities with attributes in common, in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I am designing a database model of a doctor's office and pharmacy and the requirements ask to store data about **customers** and **patients**, a customer is somebody who buys in the pharmacy and a patient who see the doctor, a customer can be patient at the same time and viceversa. How to manage this situation? If I create one entity for each one then, there is the probability that a person would be on both tables. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods:

1. One table called persons table, has files 'is_customer' and 'is_patient' that can be true/false
2. Three tables, one for people which stores all of their relevant data (names, address, phone number, etc) with a unique ID, one table for patients which is just a table of unique id's and references to the people table, and one table for customers which is just a table of unique ids and references to the people table.

Comment: Option 1, but I don't know that the indicator columns are even necessary - those values could be created based on the presence of `person_id`/etc in related tables.

Comment: Yeah, that's what option 2 is all about, the creation of those related tables referencing the first one :).

Answer (score 2):

If the data for customer and patient is exactly the same, you can have a single table with personal information and a `type` column that could either be a bit or an integer. This `type` column will tell you whether the record is for a patient or a customer. I don't see the repeated records on the case where a patient is also a customer as a big issue  but if you want to avoid this situation, you'll have to create a linking table. Something like:

```
person
(id, name, address, ...)
```

And

```
person_type( person_id, type_id)
```

A person that's both a customer and a patient will have 2 entries in this table; one for each `type` (customer/patient).